# REST API access to information in Development Panel

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying this rest api ( Using JIRA 7.13) , to get the development information  ( branches associated ) to JIRA key . however I am getting invalid JIRa key

```
http://<JIRA-IP>/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/summary?issueId=<JIRAkey>
```

getting this error

```
 {"errorMessages":["An invalid ID was provided: 'jira key'"],"errors":{}}
```

any pointer would be highly appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to use *jiraIssueId*, not *jiraIssueKey*.

The REST API above will provide you only the total number of branches. To get more information about branches, you will have to use `dev-status/1.0/issue/detail` API.

**Example:**
`https://jira.yourdomain.com/rest/dev-status/1.0/issue/detail?issueId=358491&applicationType=stash&dataType=pullrequest`

**Tip:** Use *Development Tools* (<kbd>F12</kbd>) in your browser to listen what's requested and received and you can learn more about these private API endpoints (take a look at the *Network* tab).

Comment: Thanks CraZ will try and let you know